# Python Extension for Visual Studio Code will not install

Tags: python

When trying to install from this location:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

It opens up Visual Studio Code just fine.

A dialogue box at the bottom right hand corner reads:

"The 'Python' extension is recommended for this file type."

Two buttons appear: Install and Show Recommendations.

I click on the Install Button

If I go to the Extensions Button on the left hand side of the interface, it appears to show current progress. However, it just keeps going from left to right, seemingly showing that it is being installed, but it never happens.

Python 3.8.3 has been installed and verified on my system.

Visual Studio Code Version Information:

Version: 1.45.1 (user setup)
Commit: 5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
Date: 2020-05-14T08:27:35.169Z
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

Is there another way to install this extension?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try reinstalling VS Code, and before you do anything install the python extension from directly inside VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried uninstalling and reinstalling - same problem. Spins and spins...

Comment: What is your OS? (note: that the system install of Python on macOS is not supported).
Did you install python interpreter?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro. Python Interpreter is installed. 3.8.3

Comment: Just installed via the VSIX package. Solved the issue.